# Prototype-based inheritance specified in the function declaration

Tags: javascript, inheritance, requirejs, prototype

Let's say I have a "class" like this one (I'm using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)):

**myClass.js**

```
define(function() {

  return function() {

    this.color = 0;

    this.setColor = function(color) {
      this.color = color;
    }    
  };    
});
```

If I want to enable inheritance, I can do this:

```
 // later, in another file...
 myClass.prototype = new superclass();
```

But why can't I just define the prototype directly inside the function declaration instead?

```
define(['superclass'], function(superclass) {

  return function() {

    this.color = 0;

    this.setColor = function(color) {
      this.color = color;
    }

    this.prototype = new superclass;
  };    
});
```

If I run this, `myClass` doesn't inherit any of the `superclass`'s methods. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just :

```
define(['superclass'], function(superclass) {

  var myClass = function() {

    this.color = 0;

    this.setColor = function(color) {
      this.color = color;
    }


  };

  myClass.prototype = new superclass;    
  return myClass;

});
```

You can make whatever you want before returning in the define.

Answer (score 1):

This would have worked (at least in FF and Chrome). Notice however, that each instance will have it's own prototype -- which is an unnecessary complication in most cases.

```
define(['superclass'], function(superclass) {

  return function() {

    this.color = 0;

    this.setColor = function(color) {
      this.color = color;
    }

    this.__proto__ = new superclass;
  };    
});
```

`prototype` is a property of constructors. It doesn't correspond to the prototypes of objects. `__proto__` does, but it hasn't been standardized yet.